# Using Objective-C/C static library in C++ command line tool project

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos

I've created an Objective-C/C static library which I want to use in separated project which is developed under C++

Here is a code of static library:

Info.h

```
const char * GetSomeInfo();
```

Info.m

```
#import "Info.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Info : NSObject

- (NSString *)someInfo;

@end

@implementation Info

- (NSString *)someInfo
{
    return @"getting some info";
}

@end

const char * GetSomeInfo()
{
    Info *info = [[Info alloc] init];
    return [[info someInfo] UTF8String];
}
```

Then I added Info.h and Info.a into my main C++ Xcode project which looks like command line tool created in Xcode:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Info.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const char *someInfo = GetSomeInfo();
    printf("some info: %s", someinfo);
    return 0;
}
```

I added Info.a into project settings -> link binaries with libraries. Also added -ObjC flag to the project. 
As result I receive linker errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "GetSomeInfo()",
>   referenced from:
>         _main in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

How to fix the problem above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Info.h, try wrapping the function prototype GetSomeInfo() in an extern "C" and #ifdef __cplusplus statement (starts with 2 underlines), like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    const char * GetSomeInfo();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```